# Setting a Calendar to a knowledge session dynamically inside the rules file

Tags: java, calendar, quartz-scheduler, drools

I want to attach a `Calendar` to a knowledge session from inside the rules file.

Currently, I am doing it by writing the required code in the Java file:

**`ClassCalendar.java`**:

```
package app1;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.time.Calendar;

import org.quartz.impl.calendar.WeeklyCalendar;

public class ClassCalendar {

  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      WeeklyCalendar weekDayCal = new WeeklyCalendar();
      weekDayCal.setDaysExcluded(new boolean[] { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false });
      weekDayCal.setDayExcluded(java.util.Calendar.TUESDAY, true);
      Calendar calendar = new CalendarWrapper(weekDayCal);

      String ruleFilePath = "src/main/resources/rules/ruleFile1.drl";
      KieSession kSession = KSessionUtil.buildKSession(ruleFilePath);
      kSession.getCalendars().set("calendar", calendar);

      kSession.insert(new String("hello"));
      kSession.fireAllRules();

      System.out.println("Bye");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**`CalendarWrapper.java`**:

```
package app1;

import org.kie.api.time.Calendar;
import org.quartz.impl.calendar.WeeklyCalendar;

// A class to act as a converter from Quartz Calendar to Drools Calendar
public class CalendarWrapper implements Calendar {
  private WeeklyCalendar cal;

  public CalendarWrapper(WeeklyCalendar cal) {
    this.cal = cal;
  }

  public boolean isTimeIncluded(long timestamp) {
    return cal.isTimeIncluded(timestamp);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }

}
```

**`KSessionUtil.java`**:

```
package app1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.KieBaseConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.Message;
import org.kie.api.builder.Results;
import org.kie.api.conf.EqualityBehaviorOption;
import org.kie.api.conf.EventProcessingOption;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSessionConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.runtime.conf.TimedRuleExectionOption;
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle;

public class KSessionUtil {

  public static KieSession buildKSession(String ruleFilePath) {
    List<String> ruleFilePathList = new LinkedList<String>();
    ruleFilePathList.add(ruleFilePath);
    return buildKSession(ruleFilePathList);
  }

  public static KieSession buildKSession(List<String> ruleFilePathList) {
    final boolean showErrors = true;
    final boolean showWarnings = true;
    final boolean showInfo = true;
    final boolean timedRuleOptionEnabled = false;

    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

    String virtualRuleFilePathFormat = "src/main/resources/ruleFile%d.drl";
    int virtualRuleFilePathIndex = 0;
    for (String ruleFilePath : ruleFilePathList) {
      virtualRuleFilePathIndex++;
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(ruleFilePath);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
      String virtualRuleFilePath = String.format(virtualRuleFilePathFormat, virtualRuleFilePathIndex);
      // System.out.println(virtualRuleFilePath);
      kfs = kfs.write(virtualRuleFilePath, kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource(fis));
    }

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    if (showErrors && results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
      System.out.println("~~ERROR~~:");
      System.out.println(results.getMessages());
      throw new IllegalStateException("### errors ###");
    }
    if (showWarnings && results.hasMessages(Message.Level.WARNING)) {
      System.out.println("~~WARNING~~:");
      System.out.println(results.getMessages());
    }
    if (showInfo && results.hasMessages(Message.Level.INFO)) {
      System.out.println("~~INFO~~:");
      System.out.println(results.getMessages());
    }

    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

    // Change the engine mode to 'stream'
    KieBaseConfiguration config = kieServices.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
    config.setOption(EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY);

    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase(config);

    KieSession kSession = null;
    if (timedRuleOptionEnabled) {
      // Set TimedRuleException to be true
      // It will make fireAllRules() asynchronous ( like fireUntilHalt() )
      // in the case of timed rules.
      KieSessionConfiguration ksconf = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
      ksconf.setOption(TimedRuleExectionOption.YES);
      kSession = kieBase.newKieSession(ksconf, null);
    } else {
      kSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
    }

    return kSession;
  }

  public static Boolean updateOrInsert(KieSession kSession, Object obj) {
    FactHandle factHandle = kSession.getFactHandle(obj);
    if (factHandle == null) {
      factHandle = kSession.insert(obj);
      return false;
    } else {
      kSession.update(factHandle, obj);
      return true;
    }
  }

  public static void fireAllRules(KieSession kSession) {
    System.out.println("Firing all rules ...");
    kSession.fireAllRules();
    System.out.println("Rules fired!");
  }

}
```

**`ruleFile1.drl`**:

```
package app1;

rule "rule1"
calendars "calendar"
when
    str: String()
then
  System.out.println("In rule - " + drools.getRule().getName());
    System.out.println("String matched " + str);
end
```

The code required to initialize and set the calendar has been written in the java file `ClassCalendar.java`:

```
WeeklyCalendar weekDayCal = new WeeklyCalendar();
weekDayCal.setDaysExcluded(new boolean[] { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false });
weekDayCal.setDayExcluded(java.util.Calendar.TUESDAY, true);
Calendar calendar = new CalendarWrapper(weekDayCal);

String ruleFilePath = "src/main/resources/rules/ruleFile1.drl";
KieSession kSession = KSessionUtil.buildKSession(ruleFilePath);
kSession.getCalendars().set("calendar", calendar);
```

Is there any way such that I am able to do all this from the rule itself, so that I can just do this inside the java file:

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    String ruleFilePath = "src/main/resources/rules/ruleFile1.drl";
    KieSession kSession = KSessionUtil.buildKSession(ruleFilePath);
    kSession.insert(new String("hello"));
    kSession.fireAllRules();

    System.out.println("Bye");
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drools, the concept of a calendar is nothing but a map of moments in time selected by calendar attributes to boolean, set as a property of a rule, permitting the rule to fire. Drools can evaluate the current date and time and permit or disallow the firing of a rule, based on such a calendar. But it does not have a way of changing this compiled property of a rule.

You can create a dynamic logic using a calendar fact defining the intervals where firing can be turned on and off ("schedule", e.g. hours of the day), insert facts defining a schedule and use rules to modify these schedule facts. For evaluating a set of facts, the schedule facts need to be evaluated against the current time, which will have to be inserted as another fact.

```
rule "determine time to..."
when
    Now( $time: time )
    Schedule( permitsAt( $time ) )
    str: ThisOrThat()
then
    //...
```

This will require a certain amount of work, but then dynamic behaviour was always more expensive... ;-)

**Edit** Note that one pair Now plus some Schedule can be put into a single rule which can be extended by the set of rules that should be valid according to this particular Schedule.

Comment: If I insert the time object at say, time=`t1`, and then fire all rules, assuming there are 10,000 rules and it takes, say 10^-3 seconds for the Drools to iterate through a rule and match its pattern with the inserted object, wouldn't the time object become obsolete by the time the Drools engine reaches the bottom part of the rules list ?

Comment: I don't think that you really need 10,000 to be active for one single event. But Drools has been built for matching many objects with many patterns. - If you think you'll have a performance problem, plan for running separate sessions, each with a set of rules and switch sessions according to date and time.

Comment: Could you please confirm the veracity of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40838487/1925388) ?

Answer (score 0):

We can write the calendar-initializing code in the rule file itself and manually call the `isTimeIncluded()` method in the RHS of the rule to check if the rule should be executed at the current time or not:

```
package app1;

import java.util.Calendar;
import org.quartz.impl.calendar.WeeklyCalendar;

rule "rule1"
when
    str: String()
then
    System.out.println("In rule - " + drools.getRule().getName());
    WeeklyCalendar weekDayCal = new WeeklyCalendar();
    weekDayCal.setDaysExcluded(new boolean[] { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false });
    weekDayCal.setDayExcluded(java.util.Calendar.TUESDAY, true);
    if ( weekDayCal.isTimeIncluded(System.currentTimeMillis()) )
    {
      System.out.println(str);
      // Other things to do
    }
end
```